# CSS: Align Span Element on List Item

Tags: html, css, list, alignment

I'm trying to align a button (span element) to be on the same line (extreme right side) of a List Item element. But no matter what display property (Inline-block, inline) I use on the CSS of the button, it always ends up showing under the line. 
You can see an example here: http://theroadmap.co/strategy/

This is my list:

```
<ol class="rectangle-list">
<li class="tooltip" title="What does a startup CEO actually do?"><a href="http://www.forbes.com/sites/kylewong/2013/11/28/quantified-startup-what-does-a-startup-ceo-actually-do/">Quantified Startup </a></li>
<p>What does a startup CEO actually do?</p>

<li class="tooltip" title="How to find your competitive advantage"><a href="http://blogs.hbr.org/2013/07/be-the-company-customers-cant/">Be the Company Customers Can't Live Without</a></li>
<p>How to find your competitive advantage</p>

</ol>
```

And this is the button I'm trying to insert at the end of each `<li>` element.

```
<!-- LikeBtn BEGIN -->
<span class="likebtn-wrapper" data-style="transparent" data-show_like_label="false" data-identifier="1" data-counter_show="false" data-popup_enabled="false" data-show_copyright="false" data-share_enabled="false"></span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//likebtn.com/js/widget.js" async="async"></script>
<!-- LikeBtn END -->
```

'

Thanks!
Dan.

Comment: Would making the likebutton have the style of display: inline-block; help?

Comment: The issue is you have no space to inline-block your like buttons. For example if you have a div with a width of 400px and then your number followed by your content that fills the rest of the space, where can you put your Like button at that point.  Make your wrapper box larger, and your Tooltip box smaller so you can then inline your like buttons.

Comment: I can't put a comment yet, so... I am think that you want something like this Try to put the span inside a <code>div</code> element and then put the style to that `div` to be `display:table;float:right;` Hope it helps.

Comment: Also you have a div outside of and LI inside your Ordered list. Put the Div inside your ordered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, change your code to look like this.

Put your div(with your LIke button) inside your li. Then add to your code this css to your like button.

```
.likebtn-wrapper.lb-loaded.lb-style-transparent.lb-popup-position-top.lb-popup-style-light {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    top: 1px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Here is what you will get.[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Cam! 

I'm trying this out by putting the like button in the li element, but the moment I put the above css in the custom.css, the entire wrapper and buttons disappear.

Upon inspection, it seems like it moves the button somewhere on top of the page (removing the "position:Absolute" brings it underneath the list element).

I'm sure it's just me doing something wrong..the above image is exactly what I'm aiming for! 

Cheers!

Comment: I just checked your code and everything is correct but your DIV is outside of the LI. Is this dynamic or static code. If its dynamic can you post to your question how your appending your code into your LI so I can help ya.

Comment: By the way, you have a huge gap on your right side of your screen. It looks like you have a Fluid layout, but your on a fixed screen size. Those two are not indicative of eachother. A fluid layout should be using % for the width not fixed element width like 1920px.

Comment: Hi Cam, You're right, my html was messed up! I figured out the correct way of writing the post: 
'<li class="tooltip" title="How to find business ideas">

<a href="http://www.bmnow.com/zen-innovation-and-startup-ideation/ " target="_BLANK">The Art of Finding Business Startup Ideas</a>

<span class="likebtn-wrapper" data-style="transparent" data-show_like_label="false" data-identifier="3" data-counter_show="false" data-popup_enabled="false" data-show_copyright="false" data-=""> </span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//likebtn.com/js/widget.js" async="async"></script>

</li>'

Comment: Re: the fluid layout vs fixed element, I noticed that as well... looks terrible. Using the default WP theme with an extended plugin that allows me to set max-width but only as decimals not as % :(

Comment: Oh, my suggestion is to go with a 100% width so that it fills the page. You will have to do some media queries for the different sizes. I would use Firefox Responsive tool (ctrl + shift + m) so that you can see how that is effected in different monitor sizes. You can then set a max-width if over a certain width.  Responsive to monitor ratios is a pain.

Comment: Thanks Cam, I'll give it a try after sorting this out. Unfortunately, I just noticed now that even though the button shows up on the line element, my element stopped being a link (can't click on ti anymore). Changing the Z-index of the like button to lower than that of the rectangle solves that problem but pushes the like button behind the rectangle again :(  any suggestions?

Comment: Just updated my answer. I forgot that with width set to 100% it covers the button. So remove the width, and put right: 0px;.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if fits the rest of your website styles, can't really test it all but maybe try adding to your .likebtn-wrapper class the following styles:

```
.likebtn-wrapper{
    margin-top:-28px;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: This would work, but if he adds the like button anywhere else it may not provide the same functionality that he wants.

Comment: @Cam of course your point stands, that's why I said that I'm not sure how would that play with the rest of the site. I guess OP could use a separate class for this specific case, but on the other hand no one really knows how that html code is generated.

Comment: I assume he is appending a like button function after <li> but inside of his OL. He is going to need to change where that DIV is posted to. Which makes no sense because he says span, but on the website he posted as an example he has a Div then his spans.

Comment: thanks guys! The developer of the plugin used spans not divs by default: 

'<span class="likebtn-wrapper" data-lang="en"></span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//likebtn.com/js/widget.js" async="async"></script>'

I might have changed them by mistake to divs, when it should be spans instead.